# Convert enum (as string) from CAPS_CASE to camelCase

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've found a solution to convert an ENUM to camelCase, but it's not elegant.

```
var underscoreToCamelCase = function(str) {
    str = (str === undefined || str === null) ? '' : str;
    str = str.replace(/_/g, " ").toLowerCase();
    return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w|\s+)/g, function(match, index) {
        if (+match === 0) return "";
        return index == 0 ? match.toLowerCase() : match.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

So, if str is MY_ENUM_STRING it will return myEnumString.

There must be a way to achieve this with a single regex match?

Comment: Would it be a problem to mention which languages' enums are you parsing? Multiple languages have'em, you know?

Comment: It's being returned from a java based restful service as json. It was decided that the angular front-end would handle converting to camel case, which is a requirement of the data being displayed.

Comment: Look, you're not a new user. Why didn't you include this info in question, along with sample data? Why do you expect people to guess the specific format?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var underscoreToCamelCase = function(str) {

  return str.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/_+(\w|$)/g, function ($$, $1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });

}
```

Comment: Why turn end of string uppercase?

Comment: CD.. - that works perfectly, under half as much code. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, please accept  this answer to mark your problem as being resolved :) thanks. @MatthewTrow